# R: stratified log rank test error "argument size is missing"

Tags: r, debugging, survival-analysis

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
survdiff(Surv(time, status) ~ pat.karno + strata(inst), data=lung)
```

This is the sample code from the `help(survdiff)` page. I want to perform stratified log rank test (stratified by `inst`) but when I run the above code I get the following error:

"Error in strata(inst) : argument "size" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In strata(inst) :
  the method is not specified; by default, the method is srswor"

Comment: cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: @mt1022 Yes, I thought it's strange that code from the documentation would produce such an error. However, I am still getting the same error...any idea why?

Comment: have you tried to run the code in a clean R session by restart R then type the above code?

Comment: @mt1022 Yes, it works if I use a clean R session but does not work if I use my own analysis file...I don't understand why

Comment: I guess some functions used by `survival` might be masked by other functions with the same name. I am not sure. We can not give too much help without a reproducible data. Or you can try call each function with package name added, like `survival::survdiff(survival::Surv(time, status) ~ pat.karno + survival::strata(inst), data=lung)
`. does this help?

Comment: @mt1022 It worked! I am also having trouble with `summary(survfit(survival::Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml))` it works in a new session but not with my own file. I tried `summary(survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = survival::aml))` but not luck?